# How to change the User Agent string in Chrome browser on Android (mobile phone)

Tags: chrome-for-android, android-10, user-agent-string

I've looked all over the internet, does anyone know how to change the user agent the google chrome for Android browser sends out?  Trying to do this on my dev phone.  If not has anyone been able to accomplish this using a proxy server?

Phone:  Chrome for Android

User Agent String (that I want to change):  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-G960U) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36

Any tips would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you are connected to PC - there is [Chrome Remote Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/) and from there you should be able to [change the user agent string](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/override-user-agent/), but you should clarify the environment (i.e. proxy only, if a different chrome based browser allowed, etc.)

Comment: This is directly on an android mobile device with no pc attached.  I wanted to have the end result untethered to a PC so am willing to use a proxy to accomplish this. 
 I was able to find a workaround which was to use firefox and check the "desktop mode" checkbox (tried the same thing for chrome and it doesn't work).  I feel like not being able to change this is also a privacy issue in some sense(maybe that will make people bubble up).

Comment: Note that you are free to send your own feedback to Google: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid but given that Android allows for different Browsers/browser engines to run on the platform, other apps like Firefox may serve your needs better.

Answer (score 1):

My [ChromeXt](https://github.com/JingMatrix/ChromeXt) Xposed module is capable of it. See its README:

```
## User-Agent spoofing

One can edit the User-Agent from the Info panel of Eruda console. A valid User-Agent should contain only ASCII characters. Currently, ChromeXt only changes the User-Agent HTTP header, which works well but is deprecated.

For Chromium based browsers, when the User-Agent spoofing is not taking effects, refresh the page using the reload button in the page menu. (By contrast, a swipe refresh might be insufficient.)

Note that the DevTools can also change User-Agent.
```